# Add space as suffix in restructuredtext's section-numbering directive for epub output

Tags: python, epub

How do I add a space in reStructuredText's section-numbering directive, like such:

```
.. section-numbering:
  :suffix:
```

This then is run through rst2epub. The result for html output is &nbsp; but in epub format, this gets eaten and the section number jams.

if I put just typed spaces, I get this in the epub:

```
System Message: ERROR/3 (  <string>  , line 9) 
Error in "section-numbering" directive: invalid option value: (option: "suffix"; value: None) argument required but none supplied. 
.. section-numbering::
    :suffix:
```

If I put &nbsp; then I get this in the epub

```
1.1&nbsp;About this document
```

In the source code, the leading ampersand is replaced by &amp;

Any clues? I'm willing to try any values you people come up with and report on it.

I am using FBreader on windows, but the target is Aldiko on Android.

Comment: What? Nobody? Do I need to rephrase?